# Postfix client host rejected

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix, smtp

I set up Postfix+Courier+Roundcube on Ubuntu 12.04, but when I try to send an email with Roundcube, I receive the following error:

**/var/log/mail.log :**

```
Dec 30 20:54:35 server postfix/smtpd[31465]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 30 20:54:35 server postfix/smtpd[31465]: Anonymous TLS connection established from localhost[127.0.0.1]: TLSv1.1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
Dec 30 20:54:35 server postfix/smtpd[31465]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 554 5.7.1 <localhost[127.0.0.1]>: Client host rejected: Access denied; from=<sender@mydomain.net> to=<receiver@gmail.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.mydomain.net>
Dec 30 20:54:35 server postfix/smtpd[31465]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
```

Not sure how this could be, given my settings:

**/etc/postfix/main.cf :**

```
# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
# smtpd_use_tls=yes
# smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
# smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

#SASL
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = server.mydomain.net
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = mydomain.net
mydestination = mail.mydomain.net, mydomain.net, localhost.mydomain.net, localhost
#mydestination =
relayhost = 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
mynetworks_style = host

masquerade_domains = mail.mydomain.net mydomain.net !sub.dyndomain.com
masquerade_exceptions = root

local_recipient_maps =
mydestination =
delay_warning_time = 4h
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 450
maximal_queue_lifetime = 7d
minimal_backoff_time = 1000s
maximal_backoff_time = 8000s
smtp_helo_timeout = 60s
smtpd_recipient_limit = 16
smtpd_soft_error_limit = 3
smtpd_hard_error_limit = 12

smtpd_helo_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_hostname, reject_invalid_hostname, permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated, permit_mynetworks, warn_if_reject reject_non_fqdn_sender, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit
smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_non_fqdn_recipient, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_destination, check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023, permit
smtpd_data_restrictions = reject_unauth_pipelining

smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_delay_reject = yes
disable_vrfy_command = yes

alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases
virtual_mailbox_base = /var/spool/mail/virtual
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_mailbox.cf
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_alias.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf

virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000

content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

**/etc/postfix/master.cf :**

```
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# Do not forget to execute "postfix reload" after editing this file.
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       -       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       -       -       0       tlsproxy

submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_unauth_destination,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
#  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
smtps     inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous,noplaintext
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
#  -o syslog_name=postfix/smtps
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
#628       inet  n       -       -       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       -       60      1       pickup
  -o content_filter=
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks
cleanup   unix  n       -       -       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       -       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       -       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       -       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       -       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       -       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
relay     unix  -       -       -       -       -       smtp
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       -       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
retry     unix  -       -       -       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       -       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       -       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       -       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       -       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Recent Cyrus versions can use the existing "lmtp" master.cf entry.
#
# Specify in cyrus.conf:
#   lmtp    cmd="lmtpd -a" listen="localhost:lmtp" proto=tcp4
#
# Specify in main.cf one or more of the following:
#  mailbox_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#  virtual_transport = lmtp:inet:localhost
#
# ====================================================================
#
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
#cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
# Old example of delivery via Cyrus.
#
#old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
#  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/cyrus/bin/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# ====================================================================
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix  -   n   n   -   2   pipe
  flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py
  ${nexthop} ${user}

amavis  unix    -   -   -   -   2   smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o max_use=20

127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n   -   -   -   -   smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o local_recipient_maps=
  -o relay_recipient_maps=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions= -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
  -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
  -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
```

relevant part of **/etc/roundcube/main.inc.php**

```
// ----------------------------------
// SMTP
// ----------------------------------

// SMTP server host (for sending mails).
// To use SSL/TLS connection, enter hostname with prefix ssl:// or tls://
// If left blank, the PHP mail() function is used
// Supported replacement variables:
// %h - user's IMAP hostname
// %n - http hostname ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])
// %d - domain (http hostname without the first part)
// %z - IMAP domain (IMAP hostname without the first part)
// For example %n = mail.domain.tld, %d = domain.tld

$rcmail_config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://127.0.0.1';

// SMTP port (default is 25; 465 for SSL)
$rcmail_config['smtp_port'] = 465;

// SMTP username (if required) if you use %u as the username Roundcube
// will use the current username for login
$rcmail_config['smtp_user'] = '';

// SMTP password (if required) if you use %p as the password Roundcube
// will use the current user's password for login
$rcmail_config['smtp_pass'] = '';

// SMTP AUTH type (DIGEST-MD5, CRAM-MD5, LOGIN, PLAIN or empty to use
// best server supported one)
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_type'] = '';

// Optional SMTP authentication identifier to be used as authorization proxy
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_cid'] = null;

// Optional SMTP authentication password to be used for smtp_auth_cid
$rcmail_config['smtp_auth_pw'] = null;

// SMTP HELO host 
// Hostname to give to the remote server for SMTP 'HELO' or 'EHLO' messages 
// Leave this blank and you will get the server variable 'server_name' or 
// localhost if that isn't defined. 
$rcmail_config['smtp_helo_host'] = 'mail.mydomain.net';

// SMTP connection timeout, in seconds. Default: 0 (no limit)
$rcmail_config['smtp_timeout'] = 0;
```

Any ideas?  I feel like I've reached a dead end here.

Comment: Kind of odd it accepted an anonymous connection when you have this: `smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous`.  IMHO, in `smtpd_sender_restrictions`, put `permit_mynetworks` first..

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried disabling the `nonanonymous` line, and I also moved `permit_mynetworks` at the front of the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` line.  Neither seemed to make any difference.  I'm starting to think it might be a DNS/Apache issue.

Comment: What is `etc...` doing in your log message? Did you _edit_ out things from the log? This may not be helpful...

Comment: I cut out the name of the cipher for the sake of brevity.  But it's back now, if you want to have a look.

Comment: The issue is your smtpd_client_restrictions = reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client blackholes.easynet.nl does not have a permit, meaning there is an implicit reject at the end of that list

Comment: That was a good suggestion, but commenting that line out doesn't make any difference.  By the way, I should say that I can easily send mail using `telnet localhost 25`... Perhaps Roundcube is the problem.

Comment: Check master.cf, the problem could be there. What is the port roundcube is using for submission?

Comment: @Phll the noanonymous option is the default, even commenting it out, it remains, have you configured the SMTP settings of roundcube to use authentication?

Comment: UPDATE: I just added the contents of master.cf and Roundcube's main.inc.php

Answer (score 2):

You defined smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous ( this is also the default). 
In your roundcube config the line

```
$rcmail_config['smtp_server'] = 'ssl://127.0.0.1';
```

defines to use ssl. 
For anonymous ssl connections are rejected you have to provide an username and password for the connection. 
But you have defined none:

```
// SMTP username (if required) if you use %u as the. username Roundcube
// will use the current username for login
$rcmail_config['smtp_user'] = '';

// SMTP password (if required) if you use %p as the password Roundcube
// will use the current user's password for login
$rcmail_config['smtp_pass'] = '';
```